# Stray border in table column header

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS in my header:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    table, td
    {
        border-color: #600;
        border-style: solid;
    }

    table
    {
        border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
        border-spacing: 0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    td
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 4px;
        border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
        background-color: #FFC;
    }
</style>
```

And the following table in my page body:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 100px;">column</th><th style="width: 180px;">column</th><th style="width: 100px;">column</th><th style="width: 100px;">column</th>
        <th style="width: 180px;">column</th><th style="width: 180px;">column</th> <th>column</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td><a href="">text</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

See how there is a left border on the first column header? What would be causing this, and how can I get it to go away?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your `table` style

```
 table
    {
        border-width: 0 0 1px 0px;
        border-spacing: 0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
```

Also add a left border to a TD tag so that there will be left order on td and not on th.

```
td
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 4px;
        border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
        background-color: #FFC;
    }​
```

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tFQJe/6/)

Comment: To clarify, the syntax is [top] [right] [bottom] [left]. You set 1px on [left] so there is a border on the left.

Comment: There is no left border in 2nd row check ur fiddle 

http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/tFQJe/5/

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your css:

```
tr{border-left:1px solid #000;}
tr:first-child{border-left:none;}
```

otherwise you will get not border on left

check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/KNNeZ/

Answer (score 1):

**DEMO** : [Border Corrected](http://jsfiddle.net/tFQJe/4/)
 I have added `margin:20px;` on `table` for clarity you can remove it later